# Deny the installation of apps or add new accounts (kiosk mode)

Tags: security, settings, kiosk-mode

I have a tablet that I want to give to people to go on the internet, but I don't want them to mess with it (install/unistall apps, add new accounts, change relevant options, etc).

Is there a way to **lock** the device so that it can only be used to go on the internet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/blog/2011/10/kiosk-mode-on-android/) promises this amongst [others](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kiosk%20mode&c=apps), see its [entry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) on Google Play.

With Android's rapid development, this is however a rather quick moving target.

I suggest you search also for 'android kiosk mode' on [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=android%20kiosk%20mode) or of course in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kiosk%20mode&c=apps).

Besides this: There's already a question for that on stackoverflow:
[Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)