# Samsung Galaxy Tab mass deployment

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, kiosk-mode

Device - Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 / Android 4.0.3

We are about to deploy 70 Samsung Galaxy Tabs for users who will be allowed only to use web browser to access document library. We created a Joomla site for document library.

How do I remove all the unnecessary apps from the screen except the
browser? Should I remove them one by one?

How to block access to other apps or setting?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=child+lock&submit=search

Comment: Don't. It will take 30 seconds to circumvent and when someone does it will make you look like a fool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply removing widgets and shortcuts from the screen will only prevent the very inexperienced (i.e. those who never used an Android device before) from accessing other apps, and not even sure for them. If your goal is to prevent *most* people from doing so (the very experienced will *always* find a way to circumvent your protection), you rather need something like a Kiosk-Mode.

Recomended readings/references on this:

- [Deny the installation of apps or add new accounts (kiosk mode)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24342/deny-the-installation-of-apps-or-add-new-accounts-kiosk-mode) -- another Q&A here on our site
- [Child-proofing an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25149/child-proofing-an-android-phone) -- again a Q&A at Android Enthusiasts
- [KioWare - Kiosk System Software](http://www.kioware.com/android.aspx) -- an Android Kiosk solution
- [Kiosk Mode on Android with SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/blog/2011/10/kiosk-mode-on-android/) -- also mentioned in the first Q&A
- [Kiosk mode on Android](http://onkarsingh.sys-con.com/node/2038003) -- a blog on the topic
- [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=android+%2B%22kiosk+mode%22) on the topic
- [German Overview](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435325/) on App Lockers ([Google Translate version](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F435325%2FUebersicht-App-Locker) of the same page)

Btw: If you initialize all those tablets using the same Google Account, you can easily manage installations via your computers web browser (just a hint along).

Comment: I like the way that use same google account. I did not think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you like that! Came to my mind at the last moment it would be nice to have a central maintenance at least for a part of the tasks :) Would also be interesting to know what "locking variant" you decided on.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to remove each app shortcut and/or widget from the launcher one at a time.
2. I would start looking into password-protecting the apps on the tablet as you would for a young child.  See these related questions: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=child+lock&submit=search

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sounds like that I have to play with all 70 Tabs to remove it one by one. I don't think Android tab or Galaxy Tab is ready for business purpose.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for business. It's not ready for arbitrary and pointless restrictions on what can be done with it, especially when those restrictions would just cause the devices to end up smashed against brick walls.